# How to enable @UseAdviceWith in Camel tests

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and I'm trying to write some tests that use Spring context and @UseAdviceWith annotation. What I need is to make @UseAdviceWith annotation work properly (to not to start Camel context before it is altered) and I found two ways: one is to add loader attribute like this (that was mentioned in Camel in Action book)

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml"},
        loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
```

Another way is to use

```
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
```

What is the difference and what is the right way of using it in unit tests? The version of Camel I currently have to use is 2.15.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference

- `@BootstrapWith` was **introduced with Spring 4.1**
- For older Spring versions use `@ContextConfiguration`s `loader` parameter

Both of them are Spring annotations, not Camel!

> what is the right way of using it in unit tests

Camel offers [three different Spring testing modes](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/spring-testing.html). To use `@UseAdviceWith` you have to use "[Camel Enhanced Spring Test](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/spring-testing.html#SpringTesting-CamelEnhancedSpringTest)".

If you are using SpringBoot, there was an issue with `@UseAdviceWith` that was [fixed in Camel 2.21](https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-2.21.0/).

JUnit 5 is supported in Camel 3.0. Camel 2.x supports JUnit 4 or the vintage runner of JUnit 5.

In general it is a huge muddle how to correctly configure Camel-Spring-Testing because it depends on the test mode and at least on the versions of Camel, JUnit and Spring. If you add SpringBoot you have another dependency.

However, this is a working Route test class signature with Camel 2.24, SpringBoot 2.1, Spring 5.1 and JUnit Vintage

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
        [Classes to load for the test]
    }
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@UseAdviceWith
public class MyTestClass { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using SpringBoot, just @RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) with XML configuration.

Comment: Am I right, that in case of @SpringBootTest and RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) I don't need to add BootstrapWith in order to make UseAdviceWith feature work correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think so because the `CamelSpringBootRunner` probably does for a SpringBoot Camel test what `@BootstrapWith` does for a Spring Camel test (without Boot)